# Express does not properly follow server.js specifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am very new to learning and using the MERN stack. Currently, I am having a problem where when I try to run "nodemon server", the port opens on  instead of  despite specifying in server.js that I want it to start on 5000. I am having trouble sending POST requests to  using Insomnia with the current server.js code below (I get a 404 error) and think that this might be causing the POST command to fail. Moreover, it also doesn't run `console.log('Server is running on port: ${port}');` into the terminal I am running the server from. Any feedback is appreciated.

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

const courseRouter = require("./routes/course");
const termRouter = require("./routes/term");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user");

app.use("/course", courseRouter);
app.use("/term", termRouter);
app.use("/user", userRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: "require("dotenv").config();" What is the port value of the env var on the config file?

Comment: Or try just with `const port = 5000;` just for checking

Comment: @fedeteka I used `const port = 5000;` then ran "nodemon server" but it still runs on port 3000 instead of 5000.